# Start pavucontrol as invisible window in background on xfce4

Tags: xfce, pulseaudio

I'd like to be able to start the `pavucontrol` application and keep it in background but without a visible window.

My plan is having it open, in this background mode, during session start (from `~/.xsession`).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

From the [PulseAudio Volume Control 4.0 Overview](https://freedesktop.org/software/pulseaudio/pavucontrol/#overview): *PulseAudio Volume Control (pavucontrol) is a simple GTK based volume control tool ("mixer") for the PulseAudio sound server.* In other words, it's apparently just a GUI frontend.

Running a GUI frontend in the background would seem to be pointless. But if you *really* want to, you might write a script calling a window positioning utility (e.g. `wmctrl`) to toggle its position between a point off the screen so it's not visible (e.g. x=3000 where display width is only 1920) and a point within the field of view.

Comment: It seems pointless, but when it's open in foreground, a nasty headphone buzz disappears. This is the only workaround that works. Either I start the GUI in background, or I start the client frontend (not server) in background.